# Handling large JSON file with iron-ajax, iron-list and loading via iron-scroll-threshold

Tags: javascript, ajax, polymer, web-component, polymer-starter-kit

I'm trying to load a large JSON file into my view which has over 1000 items and I would like the view to import only 20 at a time. Everytime I use `iron-list` it only renders 3 items until I resize the window and then loads all the items in the json at once.

Any idea how I can render 20 items first and then as I scroll to the bottom, I get more items?

Thanks.

```
<dom-module id="fetch">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
      }
      paper-card{
        margin-bottom: 1em;
        padding: 1em;
      }
    </style>
    <h2>Hello [[prop1]]</h2>
    <content class="horizontal">
      <paper-material>
          <iron-ajax
              auto
              url="/some.json"
              handle-as="json"
              last-response="{{ajaxResponse}}"
              debounce-duration="300"></iron-ajax>

<iron-scroll-threshold on-lower-threshold="loadMoreData" id="threshold">
        <iron-list items="[[ajaxResponse]]" scroll-target="threshold">
          <template>
            <paper-card>
              <div id="card-content">
                <h4>User:{{item.val}}</h4>
                <h4>{{item.val2}}</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="card-action">
                <paper-button>Icon</paper-button>
                <paper-button>Like</paper-button>
                <paper-fab>Open</paper-fab>
              </div>
            </paper-card>
          </template>
        </iron-list>
      </iron-scroll-threshold>
      </paper-material>
    </content>
  </template>

  <script>

    Polymer({
      is: 'fetch',

      properties: {
        prop1: {
          type: String,
          value: 'fetch'
        },
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the container (`<content class="horizintal>`) of your `iron-list` does not have an explicit size, which can cause issues.

According to the [docs](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-list)

> Important: iron-list must either be explicitly sized, or delegate
>   scrolling to an explicitly sized parent. By "explicitly sized", we
>   mean it either has an explicit CSS height property set via a class or
>   inline style, or else is sized by other layout means (e.g. the flex or
>   fit classes).

alternatively you can fire a resize event when you set the data:

```
document.querySelector('iron-list').fire('iron-resize');
```

Comment: I went through that part but I would get undefined on 'fire' so I completely gave up on that library for now. Felt, it's not stable enough to build a complex app, when the core components are inconsistent.

Comment: just give your container or the `iron-list` an explicit size, then you don't need to to fire the event. If your `iron-list` is part of another element, you need to use `this.$$('iron-list')`